# Using enhanced for loop to search for a specific character, but only prints the first matching character in an ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

This is one of my method in my program. When I tried to search for the course code from one of the selection of characters: j, g, or t; it only prints the first line it finds and never searches for the next course code.

NKDSG Foo 12.1 5 T

YDSSE Kim 12.1 5 J

ESATF Lar 23.5 10 J

```
   private Dogs searchForDogsByCourse(String dogsCode)
    {

        System.out.printf("%27s%27s%27s%27s%n","ID","Name","Running Time","Penalty");
        int i = 0;
        for(Dogs dogs : dogsList)
        {
            i++;
            if(dogs.getCourseCode().equalsIgnoreCase(dogsCode))
            {   
                System.out.printf("%27s%27s%27.2f%27d",dogs.getDogId(), 
dogs.getName(), dogs.getDogRuntime(), dogs.getPenalty());

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I searched for J, it only prints first one it matches and ends the loop.

ID       Name        Running Time        Penalty

YDSSE          Kim         12.1                5

Comment: What do you expect `return dogs;` to do?

Comment: @Tunaki oh, I that shouldn't be there. I forgot to delete it.

Comment: your problem is with printing ?

Comment: The answer [that solved the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926885/using-enhanced-for-loop-to-search-for-a-specific-character-but-only-prints-the#comment71034536_41926934) is exactly about that part of the code, so obviously it was still in the code... The duplicate explains it.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks :)! I've been working for this program for hours; I just ignore everything and I was concentrating more on the results in my program.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement in the if  brings you out of the method.you should remove this statement to allow the for loop to continue. You Can put all the correct results in an array, and return this array at the end of the method

Comment: Thank you so much man! This was the only part of my code that didn't work and you saved me from sitting here for another an hour. Thanks!